# NO puedo cambiar el password en directorio activo estoy usando ldaprecord.com

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, activedirectory, openldap

Estoy siguiendo las indicaciones de la documentacion para realiza el cambio de password a un usuario de red con ledaprecord, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    $user = ActiveDirectoryUser::where('samaccountname', '=', 'hpalacio')->first();
    $user->unicodepwd = 'nuevopass2023';

    try {
        $user->save();
        $user->refresh();
        // si se realiza el cambio entra en esta
    } catch (\LdapRecord\Exceptions\InsufficientAccessException $ex) {
        // si no tiene permisos entra en esta
    } catch (\LdapRecord\Exceptions\ConstraintException $ex) {
        // si no cumple con las reglas del DA para el cambio del pass entra en esta
    } catch (\LdapRecord\LdapRecordException $ex) {
        // cualquier error o fallo entra en esta
        $error = $ex->getDetailedError();
        $error->getErrorCode();
        $error->getErrorMessage();
        $error->getDiagnosticMessage();
    }
```

Al intentar el cambio me saca el siguiente error:

> You must be connected to your LDAP server with TLS or SSL to perform this operation.

Al consultar la documentacion dicen que debo habilitar el TLS entonces en las variables de configuracion paso **LDAP_TLS=false** a **LDAP_TLS=true**

Ahora al intentar el cambio me saca este error:

> ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Server is unavailable
> La verdad no se que hacer si alguien ya ha pasado por este mismo problema por favor una ayuda no estaria mal.

Estoy usando laravel y ldaprecord.